# check validation on input field changed

Tags: jquery

I'm customizing my codes. Here is the html

```
<div><input type="text" id="phone" /></div>
<div><input type="text" id="name" /></div>
```

jquery

```
    function checkvalid(id){
        if(id == $('#phone')){
            if($('#phone').val() != ''){
                if(!$.isNumeric($('#phone').val())){
                    $('#phone').closest('div').append('<p id="text_phone" class="validate">Not a Valid Number</p>');
                    $('#phone').next('.validate').hide().fadeIn(2000);


                }}}
    }

    $('input').each(function(){
                $(this).change(function(){
                        var chkid = $(this).attr('id');
                        checkvalid(chkid);
                        //$(this).next('.validate').fadeToggle(2000);



                });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wkg5Q/5/)

But seems not working the change function....

Comment: Your missing closing brackets on your 'input' .each function..

Comment: it's my mistake while cusomizing my code...

Comment: Note that you don't need an `.each()` loop, you can just say `$('input').change(function() {...` and get the same end result (a change handler will be bound to all matching elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkvalid(id) {
    console.log(id);
    if (id == 'phone' && $('#phone').val() != '') {
        if (!$.isNumeric($('#phone').val())) {
            $('#phone').closest('div').append('<p id="text_phone" class="validate">Not a Valid Number</p>');
            $('#phone').next('.validate').hide().fadeIn(2000);
        } else {
            $('#phone').next('.validate').hide(1000);
        }
    }
}

$('input').change(function () {
    var chkid = $(this).attr('id');
    checkvalid(chkid);
    //$(this).next('.validate').fadeToggle(2000);
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ctjc2/2/)

Two things I changed:

- `Use if (id == 'phone') {` not `if(id == $('#phone')){`
- I simplified you `.change()`, no need for the `.each()`

Comment: Thank you very much. But if again you place right that is number in phone then it hide the .validate text .... I tried fadeToggle but not working....

Comment: I'm facing another one problem, if you repeat typing wrong that is text rather than number it is appending text more times...

Comment: @C-Link, explain better what you mean "typing wrong that is text rather than number"

Comment: type text in number input and go to next field and again go back to number field and again type text then you'll notice the message is repeating.

Comment: @C-Link, ok got it. one sec, will fix that

Comment: @C-Link, this would be a better solution, not using `.append()` http://jsfiddle.net/rPAMJ/

Comment: Ok! Thant's good, anyway I've currently solved my problem with nextAll() to hide as it is positioned to absolute. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function checkvalid(id) {
    if (id == "phone" && $('#phone').val() != '') {
        if (!$.isNumeric($('#phone').val())) {
            alert("is not numeric");
            $('#phone').closest('div').append('<p id="text_phone" class="validate">Not a Valid Number</p>');
            $('#phone').next('.validate').hide().fadeIn(2000);
        }
    }
}


$('input').on('change', function () {
    var chkid = $(this).attr('id');
    checkvalid(chkid);
    //$(this).next('.validate').fadeToggle(2000);
});
```

Changes I made

- `id == 'phone'` instead of `id == $('#phone')`
- No need of `each`, just bind with input
- I have used `on` for event delegation

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wkg5Q/6/)